# Why won't biber-biblatex work with memoir?

Tags: biblatex, memoir, biber

Why won't biber-biblatex work with memoir? Seems that this is a longstanding issue, but I have not discovered any reliable resolution. In this mwe I get errors (i'm summarizing) like
undefined refs and citations, cannot find .bib file, biber didn't find bib file, failed to resolve 1 citation. [biber 1.9, biblatex 2.9a, memoir 3.7b, macOS X]

Several references suggest that you delete the biber par-cache in terminal, located at:

$ biber -- cache

I've done this numerous times, but it still doesn't work.

Incidentally, I have run biber-biblatex with the standard article and book classes. Most of the time, the files compile. When I get errors, deleting the cache usually works. Not so with memoir. I have placed the .bib file in the same directory as the main file and in a designated directory -- like  /Users/username/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/bibfile.bib (my preference). Are their cautions, best practices, secrets, tips that users should be aware of to make this work in memoir?

```
\begin{filecontents}{sbk.bib}
@book{knu86,
    Address = {New York},
    Author = {Donald E. Knuth },
    Publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    Title = {The TeXbook},
    Year = {1986}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[openany]{memoir}  
\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    %style=authoryear,
    %citestyle=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sbk.bib}
%\addbibresource{/Users/username/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/sbk.bib}

\begin{document}

The TeX reference \cite{knu86}
%The TeX reference \parencite{knu86}

%\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I regularly use `biber` and `biblatex` with `memoir`.  The `cache` deletion is an (annoying) unrelated problem.  Your example compiles without problem for me.

Comment: The documentclass should normally have no bearing on your `bilbatex` experience (some more specific classes load incompatible bibliography packages or change other things to cause trouble, the "big" "standard" classes such as memoir and koma do not). Your MWE worked just fine on my system. What exact errors do you get if you start with a clean directory (delete all auxiliary files) and run (pdf)LaTeX, Biber, (pdf)LaTeX, (pdf)LaTeX?

Comment: @Andrew Swann No such success for me. The file compiles just fine, as it has been. Very strange. Even created a new file, but no bibliography or proper cite.

Comment: How are you compiling the file?  Many interfaces run past the cache error from `biber`; you need to delete that cache and run `biber` again.  Once the cache is there it won't go away before you do the deletion and it won't produce a bibliography.

Comment: @moewe I started with a clean directory by deleting all the auxillary files. Didn't work. Then created a brand new directory with only one file, the main.tex. Still didn't work. Errors: Biber error: [386] Utils.pm:160> ERROR - Cannot find 'sbk.bib'!
Latexmk: Biber did't find bib file [sbk.bib]
Latexmk: Summary of warnings:
Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Latexmk: All targets (a1test.pdf) are up-to-date. Tried one more time with brand new file a3test.tex in another new directory. This time it worked!

Comment: @Andrew Swann I deleted the cache, compiled with pdflatexmk (Texshop), and in terminal pdflatex - biber - pdflatex -pdflatex --> not work. Finally, created a brand new file in a brand new directory and that worked. Shouldn't have to work so hard.

Comment: When compiling, have a careful look at the messages from `biber` - they are also written to the `.blg` file.

Comment: @moewe, since you first suggested starting with a clean directory I'll accept your answer if you write it out. Andrew thanks: I had looked at messages in the .blg,.bbl, and .bcf files. At the time, they didn't seem that useful. Now that file compiled I have a better idea what to look for in the future.

Comment: Tried a re-run with a .bib file in a remote location. Same problem(s) all over again. Sigh!

Comment: Well, my comment is definitely not a proper answer, so I will refrain from adding an answer. Anyway, what exact error do you get now if you run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX (where warnings about empty bibliography and "entrykey not found" can be ignored for the first LaTeX run)?

Comment: @moewe Errors:  Citation 'hern65' on page 1 undefined on input line 40, Biber error: [401] Utils.pm:160> ERROR - Cannot find 'sbk3.bib', Latexmk: Biber did't find bib file [sbk3.bib],  Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Collected warning summary (may duplicate other messages):
  biber a3test: Could not find bib file for 'a3test'
Latexmk: All targets (a3test.pdf) are up-to-date. Note: biber is not in the Texshop menu, so I use pdflatexmk. In terminal I can use pdflatex - biber - pdflatex,

Comment: What does "tried a re-run with a .bib file in a remote location" mean?  Biber *needs* to know where the bibliography file is. (Regarding an ealier comment:) If the only file in the directory is a `.tex` file, you can't run Biber (barring certain exceptions). If the `.bib` is "in" the `filecontents` environment, there is no `.bib` file until after the first LaTeX run. Also: if you are having trouble, stop using `latexmk` and work with individual commands. Unless you understand how all `.tex`-related files fit together, it just adds an extra way to get confused about what's going on.

Comment: @jon "tried a re-run with a .bib file in a remote location" was meant to say the .bib file was not in the local directory, but in another directory (.../texmf/bibtex/bib/bibfile.bib) in which the path wax explicitly denoted. In terminal mode I used pdflatex - biber - pdflatex - pdflatex. Within TexShop I could use pdflatexmk (not latexmk; that was a reported generated error). The point is that no matter how the compilation was done, where the file was located, which ref manager used, no bibliography. Only after I replaced two lines generated by BibDesk in each ref did I get a bibliography.

Comment: @jon thanks for your comment. I can't or don't know how to access Biber in TexShop. BibTex yes, pdflatexmk yes, Biber no. BTW, I was able to compile a bibliography with files generated by Zoltero and JabRef.

Comment: Strange. The path `~/texmf/bibtex/bib/` (on Macs there's "`Library`" in the path name, I think) should always be searched automatically, no need to mention the path. (Usually better idea to *not* include the path.). I cannot imagine why those two lines affect Biber, however. But I have never used BibDesk. Never had this "cache" problem either....

Comment: @Jon the ... represented /Users/username/Library preceding /texmf.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Swann and moewe noted one or more of the conditions below when working with memoir and biber/biblatex. So, this is meant to collect their comments, or others, and close out the question. There is no indication that this is a problem confined to memoir.

(1) ''cache deletion is an (annoying) unrelated problem''. For now it seems that we all have to just continue to grin and bear it.

(2) documentclass should normally have no bearing on your biblatex experience

(3) deleting the cache and re-running the file seems to have risen to the level of a method (judging by the evidence and suggestion of many, many users).

(4) Check .blg file in case a helpful message is written

(5) You can improve your chances of compilation by starting with a clean directory, retaining only main.tex and bibfile.bib. (graphic files, .sty files and others probably don't count)

(6) The .bib file just might be corrupted in some way not easily detected. I noticed that BibDesk inserted a couple of lines in its file. There may be others.

```
Date-Added = {2015-03-13 01:03:59 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2015-03-13 01:05:31 +0000},
```

Those lines may be a source of problems for BibDesk users. Manually removing them seemed to help my case.

(7) Running your BibDesk or other .bib file through a utility like BBEdit's  `Zap Gremlins'
may help if there are spurious characters lurking in the file.

Here, I repeat what other users have already stated over time about locating and deleting the cache. They are here just to sort of complete the post comments.

To locate the cache in terminal, run

```
biber --cache
```

To remove the cache with one stroke, so to speak

```
rm -rf `biber --cache`
```